# How to Close the Manually opened word document using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Before running the excel vba code, I have opened the Word document manually, is it possible to close that particular Word Document which is opened through Excel VBA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close the word document if it is opened using excel vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34625656/how-to-close-the-word-document-if-it-is-opened-using-excel-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't already have a hook on the Word app, something like this should do the trick:

```
Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    For Each wdDoc In wordApp.Documents
        If wdDoc.Name = "close_me.docx" Then '// rename to your doc
            wdDoc.Close SaveChange:=False '// change to true if required
            DoEvents
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```